# What comes after 小心 in 小心（？）落，请勿靠近 written on these boxes in messy handwriting?

Tags: transcription

This may be one of my more frivolous questions, but I was sitting at the tea shop, and beside me were these boxes:

> [image: box 1 a milk tea shop with messy handwriting]
>
> [image: box 2 a milk tea shop with messy handwriting]

Both these boxes have written on them in messy handwriting:

> 小心（？）落，请勿靠近

I can't figure out the missing bit.  I'm tossing up between

- [坐落](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9D%90%E8%90%BD), one box looks like this, but the meaning seems inappropriate;
- 坏土落, judging from the components, but I don't think this is a word;
- [坠落](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9D%A0%E8%90%BD), which makes logical sense to me, but that doesn't look like the characters written;
- [掉落](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8E%89%E8%90%BD), which is [Koala.sh](https://koala.sh/chat)'s guess.

Maybe the two boxes are labelled differently, too.

**Question**: What comes after 小心 in 小心（？）落，请勿靠近 written on these boxes in messy handwriting?

Answer (score 5):

it should be '坠落', the writer doesn't remember how to write it correctly.

Comment: 不但寫錯「坠」字，連「勿」字也錯了，看著就像個「豕」字

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical warning in warehouses to prevent incidents/injuries due to falling items.

小心坠落, 請勿靠近 - Be aware falling items, please do not come near/close, or please stay away.